# Top2Vec error - 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'vectors_docs'

Tags: python, topic-modeling, doc2vec

When training the Top2Vec model in Python 3.9.2  I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-edc5d3cec713> in <module>
----> 1 model = Top2Vec(documents=data, speed="learn", workers=12)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/top2vec/Top2Vec.py in __init__(self, documents, min_count, embedding_model, embedding_model_path, speed, use_corpus_file, document_ids, keep_documents, workers, tokenizer, use_embedding_model_tokenizer, umap_args, hdbscan_args, verbose)
    353                          'metric': 'cosine'}
    354 
--> 355         umap_model = umap.UMAP(**umap_args).fit(self._get_document_vectors(norm=False))
    356 
    357         # find dense areas of document vectors

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/top2vec/Top2Vec.py in _get_document_vectors(self, norm)
    545                 return self.model.docvecs.vectors_docs_norm
    546             else:
--> 547                 return self.model.docvecs.vectors_docs
    548         else:
    549             return self.document_vectors

AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'vectors_docs'
```

I have the following packages installed:

- import numpy as np
- import pandas as pd
- from copy import deepcopy
- from top2vec import Top2Vec
- import gensim

I'm kicking off the training using the code below:

```
model = Top2Vec(documents=data, speed="learn", workers=12)
```

And it gets this far through the model training:

```
2021-03-31 16:36:03,014 - top2vec - INFO - Pre-processing documents for training
2021-03-31 16:36:25,865 - top2vec - INFO - Creating joint document/word embedding
2021-03-31 17:02:53,874 - top2vec - INFO - Creating lower dimension embedding of documents
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the `Top2Vec` class you're using.

However, that error would be expected if code that was written to use certain properties/methods in `gensim-3.8.3` hasn't been adapted for the recently-released `gensim-4.0.0`, which has removed and renamed some functions for consistency.

Specifically, the `vectors_docs` property has been removed. (Also, the `vectors_docs_norms` property mentioned a couple lines above in an unexecuted branch.)

The small changes required in the calling code are covered in the [Migrating from Gensim 3.x to 4 wiki page](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4), which I've just updated to ensure it mentions `vectors_docs` specifically.

If you don't feel comfortable appkying this & any other changes to your `Top2Vec` code yourself, you may just want to report the issue to its author/maintainer, and as a temporary workaround, explicitly install the older Gensim for now. With the usual `pip`-based install, you could specify an older version with:

```
pip install gensim==3.8.3
```

Comment: For anaconda, run `conda uninstall gensim`.  Then, `conda install gensim=3.8.3`.